# Searching the string through shell script

Tags: string, shell, search

I have a file having text as :

```
value=abc

abc

def
```

I want to search for abc which is in the second line and not the one which is there in the first line through shell script. Can I get help in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use this `grep` command `grep "^abc$" file_name` to get your required result. For more refer http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Comment: anything you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

For getting "abc" in lines other than "First Line" in file :

**Assuming Solaris :**

```
awk "NR>1 {print}" /path/to/file| /usr/sfw/bin/ggrep -o "abc"
```

**Assuming Unix**

```
awk "NR>1 {print}" /path/to/file| egrep -o "abc"
```